# Equilibrium of a Partial Delayed Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have some function $f$ which depends on a time parameter $t$ and another parameter $s$, suppose $f$ satisfies some Partial Delay Differential Equation:
$$
\frac{\partial f(t,s)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f(t,s)}{\partial s} = F(f(t,s_1),\dots,f(t,s_n)). \qquad (1)
$$
for some $s_1,\dots,s_n\leq s$. Then one can find the equilibirum, i.e. the behaviour of $f$ in the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$ by leaving out the dependence on $t$, which yields the delay differential equation:
$$
f'(s)=F(f(s_1),\dots,f(s_n)), \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
which is often easier to solve.

How does one go about proving that this is a valid strategy, I mean prove that the solution of (2) indeed corresponds to the limit of the solution of (1)?

Comment: Should the your PDE be $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \color{red}s} = \dots$$ ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing!

Comment: As written, it seems that your equations (1) and (2) don't actually give a standard PDE or ODE since the right sides involve various values of $s$.  Are $s_1,\dotsc,s_n$ fixed, or are they functions of $s$?  In the latter case, it seems that you then have delay differential equations.

Comment: Yes it are indeed delay differential equations, I adapted the nomenclature in the question.